# OOP Problems - Derived Class

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class, undefined-reference, playing-cards

I am trying to figure out an undefined reference to Class::Function(). The project is one that I've seen a few responses for and I have looked at the responsesfor others and it appears that the code is similar, but I can't seem to find an answer to my specific issue. I am trying to use 2 .h files, their implementation files, and a driver to simply deal cards from a deck. I have hit a wall since I'm not 100% sure how to use derived classes. My current errors when compiling are as follows:

- **undefined reference to 'Deck::shuffleCards()'**
- **undefined reference to 'Deck::dealCard ()'**
- **undefined reference to 'Card::getCard () const'**

Any help provided is greatly appreciated. Here is the code

**CARD.H**

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Card
{

    private:
    string face; //Used to store value of face(A-K)
    string suit; //User to store value of suit(A/R/S/B)

    public:

    string getCard() const; //Returns the card.

    //Constructor
    Card(string cardFace, string cardSuit)
    {face = cardFace; suit = cardSuit;}

    //Default Constructor
    Card()
    {}
};
#endif // CARD_H
```

**Card.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CARD.H"

string Card::getCard() const
{
    //Returns the card in a format of X of Y(Ace of Shields)
    return (face + " of " + suit);
}
```

**DECK.H**

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "CARD.H"
#include <string>


using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 52;  //Standard Size of Deck. Used for calculations

class Deck : private Card
{

    private:
    Card *deckOfCards; //Creates pointer for deck.
    int currentCard; //Keeps track of the current card array location

    public:
     //Constructor for Deck. Creates a deck of cards.
    Deck() : Card()
    {
        string faces[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                    "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        string suits[] = {"Acorns", "Shields", "Bells", "Roses"};

        deckOfCards = new Card[SIZE];
        currentCard = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            deckOfCards[i] = Card(faces[i % 13], suits[ i / 13]);
        }

    }

        void shuffleCards();  //Shuffles the cards.
        Card dealCard(); //Returns a Card data type when this is called.
        void printDeck() const; //Prints the deck.
};
#endif // DECK_H
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "DECK.H"
#include "CARD.H"

/**********************************************************************
* Uses 2 arrays to shuffle the cards. The function uses
* 2 arrays and random number generation with a modulus of the size of
* the deck to find the next location of the card.
**********************************************************************/
void Deck::shuffleCards()
{
currentCard = 0;

for(int first = 0; first < SIZE; first ++)
    {
        int second = (rand() + time(0)) % SIZE;
        Card temp = deckOfCards[first];
        deckOfCards[first] = deckOfCards[second];
        deckOfCards[second] = temp;
    }

}

Card Deck::dealCard()
{
//Checks to make sure the current card location is not greater than size.
//If so, this would indicate the deck needs to be shuffled because we're
// out of cards
    if (currentCard > SIZE)
        shuffleCards();
    if (currentCard < SIZE)
        return(deckOfCards[currentCard++]);

    return deckOfCards[0];
}

 //Function used to format the printing of the deck.
 void Deck::printDeck() const
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
         cout << deckOfCards[i].getCard();
         if((i + 1) % 5 == 0) //Prints 5 cards per line.
         {
            cout << endl; //If mod expression is valid, starts new line.
         }
     }
 }
```

**Main Driver**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DECK.H"
#include "CARD.H"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Deck myDeck;
    Card myCard;


    myDeck.shuffleCards();

    for(int i = 0; i< 52; i++)
    {    
        myCard = myDeck.dealCard();
        cout << myCard.getCard() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're adding the .cpp files to your makefile/project.

Comment: This is a compile error, not a syntax error and nothing to do with derived classes. It's probably because .o files aren't being created so the compiler is unable to link them. Posting you makefile would be useful.

Comment: I'm actually using CodeBlocks to compile. Any other recommendations would be awesome.